# What are requirements of Key Usage extension of parent and child certificates?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority

This question is about validating certificates. Imagine some machine gets a leaf certificate (i.e. a certificate signed by the certificate of some CA) with specific Key Usage attributes.

Example #1: Should the machine reject the certificate if the parent certificate does not include the keyCertSign bit in Key Usage?

Example #2: Is the child Key Usage required to be a subset of parent Key Usage? Or is the child allowed to have specific Key Usage bits that are not in the parent cert?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280.html#section-4.2.1.3 has this to say:

> If the keyUsage extension is present, then the subject public key
> MUST NOT be used to verify signatures on certificates or CRLs unless
> the corresponding keyCertSign or cRLSign bit is set.  If the subject
> public key is only to be used for verifying signatures on
> certificates and/or CRLs, then the digitalSignature and
> nonRepudiation bits SHOULD NOT be set.  However, the digitalSignature
> and/or nonRepudiation bits MAY be set in addition to the keyCertSign
> and/or cRLSign bits if the subject public key is to be used to verify
> signatures on certificates and/or CRLs as well as other objects.

So the expectation is that a CA's KeyUsage will assert { keyCertSign | cRLSign } without asserting digitalSignature.  And the end-entity/leaf cert will of course want to assert digitalSignature, therefore there's no expectation of subsetting.